# Insert a div element as parent

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm just wondering if the following is possible, lets say we have a dom element and we want to wrap this element in a div. So a div is inserted between the element and it's parent. Then the div becomes the element's new parent.

But to complicate things, elsewhere we have already done things like:

```
var testElement = document.getElementByID('testID')
```

where testID is a child of the element to be warapped in a div. So after we have done our insertion will testElement still be valid?

BTW: I'm not using jquery.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

AJ

Comment: By using document.getElementByID() you search all the DOM for a specific ID. If this ID doesn't change you wont have any problems

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You can use [`replaceChild` <sup>[docs]</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild):

```
// `element` is the element you want to wrap
var parent = element.parentNode;
var wrapper = document.createElement('div');

// set the wrapper as child (instead of the element)
parent.replaceChild(wrapper, element);
// set element as child of wrapper
wrapper.appendChild(element);
```

As long as you are not using `innerHTML` (which destroys and creates elements), references to existing DOM elements are not changed.

Answer (score 5):

In pure JS you can try something like this...

```
var wrapper = document.createElement('div'); 
var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv'); 
wrapper.appendChild(myDiv.cloneNode(true)); 
myDiv.parentNode.replaceChild(wrapper, myDiv);
```

Comment: You might have a problem if `myDiv` or its descendants have bound (not inline) event handlers. They will not be cloned.

Comment: Interesting point, but he can solve this by calling "addEventListener" or "attachEvent" function again... or am i wrong? Of course he need to know which event to bind, that can be problem... or is there way to get that bound event before cloning element?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are doing your manipulation using standard DOM methods (and not innerHTML) then — yes.

Moving elements about does not break direct references to them.

(If you were using innerHTML, then you would be destroying the contents of the element you were setting that property on and then creating new content)

You probably want something like:

```
var oldParent = document.getElementById('foo');
var oldChild = document.getElementById('bar');
var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
oldParent.appendChild(wrapper);
wrapper.appendChild(oldChild);
```

Comment: Your particular example only works if `oldChild` is the only or last  child of `oldParent`. Otherwise the order of the nodes changes.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another example, only the new element wraps around 'all' of its child elements.

You can change this as necessary to have it wrap at different ranges. There isn't a lot of commentary on this specific topic, so hopefully it will be of help to everyone!

```
var newChildNodes = document.body.childNodes;  
var newElement = document.createElement('div');

newElement.className = 'green_gradient';
newElement.id = 'content';        

for (var i = 0; i < newChildNodes.length;i++) {
    newElement.appendChild(newChildNodes.item(i));
    newChildNodes.item(0).parentNode.insertBefore(newElement, newChildNodes.item(i));
}
```

You will want to modify the 'document.body' part of the newChildNodes variable to be whatever the parent of your new element will be. In this example, I chose to insert a wrapper div. You will also want to update the element type, and the id and className values.