# Assigning a div and class to each element in a for loop

Tags: jquery, html, for-loop, shopify

I'm working on a Shopify site and trying to assign a div to an array of photos.

Shopify has a page.content variant that spits out the photos in a single div, but I'd like to use a for loop to give them each a unique div and class.

The code that I have doesn't render any content, but I think that it's close to working.  It might be easier to use .addClass(), but I think I can do it without Jquery.  Any thoughts or comments would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the test [page](http://mutt-couture.myshopify.com/pages/test)

And the code that I have:

```
<div class="row products">
  <div class="product span12">
    <div class="image"> 
       {% for variant in page.content %} 
       {% if variant contains 'img' %} 
        <div class="image"> 
          <div class="span4">{{ variant.image }}</div>
        </div> 
       {% endif %} 
       {% endfor %} 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to display images you have put in `page.content` (via the Pages admin area), or all the images for a specific product? Products have variants, `page.content` does not (it's just HTML).

Comment: I'm trying to display images that are put in page.content via the admin area.  They aren't products.  It's my friends site and he wants to treat the page like a gallery.  A place where he can insert 9-12 photos that aren't products.  So, I'm trying to target the img element that's rendered from page.content and style it accordingly.  Do you think it can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Liquid is not going to work for this task. You could use javascript, something like this:

```
<script>
  var images = document.body.getElementsByTagName('img');  

  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
  {
    var parent  = images[i].parentNode;
    var sibling = images[i].nextSibling;

    var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
    wrapper.className = 'new-div';

    wrapper.appendChild(images[i]);

    if (sibling) {
          parent.insertBefore(wrapper, sibling);
    } else {
         parent.appendChild(wrapper);
    }
  }
</script>
```

See similar SO questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337587/wrapping-a-dom-element-using-pure-javascript) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938248/insert-a-div-element-as-parent).

Or you could use jQuery's [.wrap() function](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/).

Comment: Thanks Steph!  The .wrap()function worked perfectly.  Exactly what I needed.