# Using javascript to add before and after

Tags: javascript, php, html, replace

I want to know how can i add html element before some elements and after 
e.g: 
this is code which i added in real file .

```
<ul class="abcd" id="abcd></ul>
```

so how can i show it like this ( using javascript );

```
<div class="blabla">
<div class="ABCD">
   <ul class="abcd" id="abcd></ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Here someone had a similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938248/insert-a-div-element-as-parent

Answer (score 1):

```
var yourVar; // some  DOM instance
var newFirstElem; //element which should be first in yourVar

yourVar.insertBefore(newFirstElem, yourVar.firstChild);
```

THis will add as the first child. To add after just use normal append.

Edit:

Consider you have this in the beginning:

```
  <div class="blabla">
     <div class="ABCD">

     </div>
  </div>
```

And you want to add
 `<ul class="abcd" id="abcd></ul>` to div with class ABCD

`$(".ABCD").append('<ul class="abcd" id="abcd></ul>')`

You want to add to div with class blabla

`$(".blabla").append('<ul class="abcd" id="abcd></ul>')`

Consider you have already have this this

```
<div class="blabla">
         <div class="ABCD">
             <ul class="abcd" id="abcd></ul>
         </div>
      </div>
```

and now you want to add before the ul inside the div with class abcd

`$(".abcd").prepend("<ul class="abcd" id="abcd></ul>");`

jQuery makes it simpler. You can just use prepend function. This function allows you to insert whatever you like at the beginning. There are also the option of inserting at specific positions. You should take a look at:

`insertAt`

`insertBefore`

`after`

`before`

Comment: if you don't mind can you please specify it little more ? i don't have much experience in it . 
i have same condition i have to add div start before (ul) and end after (ul) there is many code before and after (ul) :

// many of html here 
<ul class="abcd" id="abcd></ul>
// some html here

Comment: can u specify the before code and after code, so it is simpler to understand.

Comment: there is a lots of html . and i have to use this in different pages so every page have different html

Comment: if this is not possible to do this id this possible to do it in jquesry-ui.js? because i am getting value of ul from jquery . i want that i could add some javascript in it so it could start a div before ul and end after ul 

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"

Comment: if you meant to say before and after code ( code which we "will"put after and before using javascript ) then it is a simple div ( div starts before the ul and ends after ul as i said above )

Comment: i tried to use it but didn't worked :
please try in jsfiddle (link below ) and give me the link if work .

http://jsfiddle.net/ZkzDk/

Comment: u havent tried what i have suggested. Please provide the fiddle with the above suggestion.

Comment: oops ! sorry i was pasted wrong link.
please check this ( you can update it ) : http://jsfiddle.net/nz1gfo3c/

Comment: there i tried this: http://jsfiddle.net/j7xqmtzo/3/
i addeds div before url which is fine and it have to end div after ul but i is ending div before the ul

Answer (score 0):

if you have a html file like this

```
<html>
<body>
<ul id="1"></ul>
</body>
```

and you what this

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div>
        <ul id="1"></ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

use this javascript

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
var b = document.getElementById("1");
var a = document.createElement("div");
x.appendChild(a);
a.appendChild(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is the code you are looking for..

```
<!doctype>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example - Javascript - Add element before/after</title>
        <script language="javascript">
        function mAddBegin()
        {
            var tNew = document.createElement('li');
            tNew.innerHTML = document.getElementById('value').value;

            var tList = document.getElementById('list');
            tList.insertBefore(tNew, tList.firstChild);
        }
        function mAddBefore()
        {
            var tNew = document.createElement('li');
            tNew.innerHTML = document.getElementById('value').value;

            var tList = document.getElementById('list');
            var tTea = document.getElementById('tea');
            tList.insertBefore(tNew, tTea);
        }
        function mAddAfter()
        {
            var tNew = document.createElement('li');
            tNew.innerHTML = document.getElementById('value').value;

            var tList = document.getElementById('list');
            var tTea = document.getElementById('tea');
            tList.insertBefore(tNew, tTea.nextSibling);
        }
        function mAddEnd()
        {
            var tNew = document.createElement('li');
            tNew.innerHTML = document.getElementById('value').value;

            var tList = document.getElementById('list');
            tList.appendChild(tNew);
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="list">
           <li>Coffee</li>
           <li id="tea">Tea</li>
           <li>Milk</li>
        </ul>
        <input type="text" id="value" />
        <input type="button" onclick="javascript: mAddBegin(); " value="Add begin" />
        <input type="button" onclick="javascript: mAddBefore(); " value="Add before 'Tea'" />
        <input type="button" onclick="javascript: mAddAfter();" value="Add after 'Tea'" />
        <input type="button" onclick="javascript: mAddEnd();" value="Add end" />
    </body>
</html>
```