# Applying links via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hullo, I am wondering how I can add a new link around/to an element, using *only* JavaScript? I am new to JavaScript, and I am sorry if this question seems stupid or too easy.

Current:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content1"></div>
    <div class="content2"></div>
</div>
```

Desired Code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content1"></div>
    <a href="http://example.com">
        <div class="content2"></div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938248/insert-a-div-element-as-parent. Instead of inserting a div element as in the post, you could replace it with an anchor element. Following this post, you could add the link to the anchor element https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710275/how-to-add-update-an-attribute-to-an-html-element-using-javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can use jQuery [`wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

```js
$('.content2').wrap('<a href="http://example.com">')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="content1">content 1</div>
    <div class="content2">content 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do our answers get downvotes? The question does have the [tag:jquery] tag.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir not sure. I think I have a serial downvoter today. Got quite a few which isn't normal

Comment: Anyways upvoted for sanity. Leaving to bed now. Grrrr!

Answer (score 3):

Just use normal DOM manipulation, nothing tricky required

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const a = container.appendChild(document.createElement('a'));
a.href = "http://example.com";
a.appendChild(document.querySelector('.content2'));

console.log(container.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="content1"></div>
    <div class="content2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a new `a` element and create a child in that element with the same content in your `div` and append the `a` element in the parent of the old `div`('.container')

```js
var content2 = document.getElementsByClassName('content2')[0];

var container = content2.parentNode;
var a = document.createElement('a');

a.setAttribute("href", "www.google.com");
container.replaceChild(a, content2);
a.appendChild(content2);
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="content1">Content1</div>    
    <div class="content2">Content2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using only pure Javascript, you can do something like this:

*1. get your div by class (you can do using getElementById if you define an id for your div)*

`var mydiv = document.getElementsByClassName('content1');`

*2. create your anchor and set an href*

`var new_anchor = document.createElement("a");
new_anchor.href = "http://example.com";`

*3. Place the div content1 inside new anchor*

`new_anchor.append(mydiv[0]);`

*4. Place your entire element inside the container again*

`var mycontainer = document.getElementsByClassName('container');
mycontainer[0].insertBefore(new_anchor, mycontainer[0].childNodes[0])`